# Call XSLT file from data:text/xml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, xslt

Have a nice day everybody

i'm trying to call a XSLT file from an XML that i'm rendering using data:text/xml, obtained from a REST.
The most basic attempt is to use this line of code:

```
window.open( 'data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent( responseData ) );
```

another attempt of mine is to open it in a modal iframe (with angular-material) setting up the src with the xml data, both tests opens the XML with the URL but with this error:

Error loading the stylesheet: unknown error **(805303f4)**

I have test it in firefox and chrome, and chrome is more clear with the error details in the console:

**Unsafe attempt to load URL** *route-to-xsl.xsl* **from frame with URL** *data:text/xml,...* **Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

I tried to use an absolute path to the stylesheet including same protocols, domains etc. but the error remains (both in iframe or new tab options).

Any help pls, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As this is client-side Javascript inside of web browsers like Firefox or Chrome I would suggest to use `XSLTProcessor` to perform the XSLT transformation, you can pull in the XSLT stylesheet using `XMLHttpRequest`, parse your `responseData` using `DOMParser` and then you can use `XSLTProcessor` for the transformation.

I don't think you will get the browser to execute an XSLT referenced in the `data` URL, unless the XSLT is embedded itself as data:

```js
var encodedXslt = 'data:application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('xslt').textContent);


var xmlCode = document.getElementById('xml').textContent;
var pi = '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="' + encodedXslt + '"?>';

var encodedXml = 'data:application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(pi + xmlCode);

window.frames.xmlDisplay.location.href = encodedXml;
```

```html
<script id="xslt" type="application/xml+xslt">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="list">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</script>

<script id="xml" type="application/xml">
  <list>
    <item>foo</item>
    <item>bar</item>
  </list>
</script>

<iframe name="xmlDisplay" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

However, it seems only Mozilla swallows that attempt and applies the XSLT, Chrome continues to complain about an unsafe attempt. So I think it is better and more portable to implement any XSLT transformation where you have the input as a Javascript string with XSLTProcessor.

Comment: hi, thanks for your time. Now: i've tried as you said here but in firefox i get an error that says **"Wating for..."** and nothing else, and in Chrome i get in the console **"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/xml"** and spits the entire XSLT, next question is: what if i need to load more than 1 XSLT because the main one imports a couple more?

Comment: That code snippet in my answer is executable ("Run code snippet") and for me with Firefox 58 it then shows an unordered HTML list meaning the XSLT was applied. As I said, it doesn't work in Chrome.  As for using XSLTProcessor from Javascript, you will need to edit your question or ask a new one with all details of a minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay, i just had to change the firefox language to see what it says in english, implementing your code in my project says: **XML Parsing Error:** and points to the **<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="_here is all the xsl encoded_ ?>** that's the error that i got now