# Make a XSLT transformation in <iframe> without src

Tags: html, xml, xslt, iframe

I want to embbed a XSLT transformation into an `<iframe>`. Here are my 2 files:

`simple.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl"?>
      <text>
        Hello World
      </text>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

`simple.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
      <body>
        Content: <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously, it doesn't work.

If I put the XML code of the `<iframe>` into a file named `simple.xml` and reference it like that `<iframe src="simple.xml">`, it works well but I don't want to have a separate XML file.

The reason is because the XML code will be provided by the user and I don't want to store it temporarily on my server just so I can reference it in the `<iframe>`, I want to do all client-side.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how can I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Won't `simple.html` be stored on the server then? If so, what is the difference between trying to hard-code the contents of the XML in the `simple.html` file, and storing `storing.xml` in the same place as `simple.html` on the server?

Comment: An is the file `simple.xsl` always the one you have shown or can that differ in the file name and/or the contents? Selecting the string value of the document node and putting it into an iframe doesn't seem much of a transformation.

Comment: In general you can run XSLT 1 in the browser's with Javascript and also write something to an iframe (since they existed in browsers) with `document.open();document.write(...); document.close();`). For instance in the https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8E where the client-side processor is used the `HTML` button basically does that (transformation `clientSideTransformer` in `main.js`, writing to iframe in `htmlToIframe` in main.js).

Comment: As an alternative that might be more compact but has less portability the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877569/call-xslt-file-from-datatext-xml/48881299#48881299 which simply uses two `data` URLs to encode the XML and XSLT does work for me now with an up-to-date Firefox and Chrome version. I am not sure however it worked anywhere if you would need to encode the XML into a data URL but then reference the XSLT as a file, I think browsers will then give you a same origin policy violation error.

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable input. Yes, `simple.html` and `simple.xsl` are both served on the server but I don't want any server-side logic (like storing a temporary `simple.xml` file every time the user provides his XML code). I also tried to inject the XML with `document.write()` but that didn't work. Your idea to use the XSLT transformation in Js (with a `XSLTProcessor` for example) is very interesting, I will dig more into that.

Comment: https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2019/test2019010602.html is an attempt to try to construct a `data` URL from an XML string where the XML is prefixed with an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction referencing a XSLT stylesheet on the server. While Firefox seems to allow that Chrome ("Unsafe attempt to load URL https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2019/test2019010601.xsl from frame with URL data:application/xml,[...]. Domains, protocols and ports must match") and Edge ("request for cross-domain XSLT denied") refuse to load the XSLT as I expected.

Comment: So the best solutions are either to use a `XSLTProcessor` or to recreate the tranformation with a `DOMParser`, am I correct?