# Transform xml to html using xslt stylesheet

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, ecmascript-6

I have one sample [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760344(v=vs.85)#xml-data-file-testxml) & [XSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760344(v=vs.85)#xslt-style-sheet-testxsl) resource. I am getting `XML` as a string from API call in javascript. While `XSLT` is present as a static resource on the server. My goal is to display `XML` content along with stylesheet in HTML document element.

I do not want to use `XSLTProcessor` for now. I would like to try the browser way. And yes both the `XML` and `XSLT` would be coming from the same server.

Code:

```
import XSL from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Roles';

export default class DisplayReport extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback(){
        var xml = '<root> <node>one</node> <nodes> <node>1</node> <node>2</node> </nodes> <node>two</node> </root>'; 
        
        var output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="'+XSL+'" ?>'+xml;
        console.log(output); //output on below line
        
        //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/assets/project/b481ca5a6f/staticresources/Roles" ?><root> <node>one</node> <nodes> <node>1</node> <node>2</node> </nodes> <node>two</node> </root>
        
        var xmlNode = this.parseXml(output);        
        console.log(xmlNode);
        const element = this.template.querySelector('div.dms');
        element.appendChild(xmlNode.documentElement);
    }

    parseXml(xmlStr){
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<template>
    <div class="dms" lwc:dom="manual">

    </div>
</template>
```

Output: (no style sheet getting applied)

```
one 1 2 two
```

Any idea what is missing here?

Comment: Why is XSLTProcessor not the browser way?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am facing this issue https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302264/new-xsltprocessor-fails-in-lwc. Maybe it is because of shadow DOM. To answer your question, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722617/1169180

Comment: I am not familiar with the tool or environment you use but if using DOMParser is the browser way and you have to use `new window.DOMParser()` in your environment then perhaps `new window.XSLTProcessor()` does work as well. The processing instruction will only work if you load an XML document from a server into a window or frame.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48881299 for using a `data:` URL with an iframe where both XML and XSLT are taken from a string.

Comment: I tried with `new window.XSLTProcessor()` but still it gives me an error `Error during LWC component connect phase: [Failed to construct 'XSLTProcessor': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.]`